# Consider the linear mapping T : P 2 ( R ) →P 2 ( R ).... Compute the matrix

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Consider the linear mapping $T:P2(R) → P2(R)$ given by,

$T p(x) = (1−x^2)p′′(x)−2xp′(x)$

Let $B1$ = {$1+x,1+x^2,1+x+x^2$} ⊂ $P2(R)$. Then $B1$ is a basis for $P2(R)$

(a)  Compute the matrix
 $M(T,B1,B1)$.

(b)  Let $p(x) = 1+2x−3x^2.$  Compute

(i)  $[p]B1$

(ii)  $[Tp]B1$

(iii) $M(T,B1,B1)[p]B1$

For part a) i got

$(0 6 6

2 2 4

-2 -6 -8)$

But i dont know if its correct and i am very confused for part b) im struggling to see what its asking me to compute.

Comment: Ok for b) i) i got (4, -1, -2) and for ii) (-24,-2,20)
definitely confused about the last one but and is this correct?

Comment: You can check your own work for part (a): the columns of the matrix are the images of the basis vectors, so check that $T[1+x]=2(1+x^2)-2(1+x+x^2)$ and so on.